# Use the Maps API Places Library to get results for type of "route" of "street address"

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The Places Library documentation suggests that you can search for types like "route" and "street address" as well as types like "stores" etc.

I have only done a quick modification of the example provided for the Places Library to search for "route" and "street address". I have had no success searching for these types in any location with any radius, it always returns zero results.

Has anyone been able to search for these types? Is this something that is available through the Places API and not the Places Library?

Is there something that must be done differently to search for these types vs types like stores, parking etc?

Thanks.